# Heroku Build Failing Due To Code Integrity

Tags: heroku, build

I have an application deployed on Heroku and I have not had problems redeploying it, up until yesterday.

I had to upgrade one of the dependencies in my package-lock.json/yarn.lock files and when trying to upload it to Heroku, I get the following:

```
 Node.js app detected
 remote:
 remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
 remote:
 remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
 remote:        NODE_ENV=production
 remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
 remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
 remote:
 remote: -----> Installing binaries
 remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.15.x
 remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   6.14.x
 remote:
 remote:        Resolving node version 10.15.x...
 remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.15.3...
 remote:        Bootstrapping npm 6.14.x (replacing 6.4.1)...
 remote:        npm 6.14.x installed
 remote:
 remote: -----> Installing dependencies
 remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
 remote:        npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
 remote:        npm ERR! sha1-hX/Kv8M5fSYluCKCYuhqp6ARsF0= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-hX/Kv8M5fSYluCKCYuhqp6ARsF0= but got sha512-rIqbOrKb8GJmx/5bc2M0QchhUouMXSpd1RTclXsB41JdL+VtnojfaJR+h7F9k18/4kHUsBFgk80Uk+q569vjPA== sha1-sAoAIwoRCMSMFp5popGq/aOqzWM=. (7897 bytes)
 remote:
 remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.P3BnU/_logs/2020-03-18T06_17_36_985Z-debug.log
 remote:
 remote: -----> Build failed
 remote:
 remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
 remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
 remote:
 remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
 remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
 remote:
 remote:        Love,
 remote:        Heroku
 remote:
 remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 remote:
 remote:  !     Push failed
```

I realize the problem resides within this line:

> npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
>        remote:        npm ERR! sha1-hX/Kv8M5fSYluCKCYuhqp6ARsF0= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-hX/Kv8M5fSYluCKCYuhqp6ARsF0= but got sha512-rIqbOrKb8GJmx/5bc2M0QchhUouMXSpd1RTclXsB41JdL+VtnojfaJR+h7F9k18/4kHUsBFgk80Uk+q569vjPA== sha1-sAoAIwoRCMSMFp5popGq/aOqzWM=. (7897 bytes)

but I do not know why it is occurring now or what triggered it (as it did not happen before).

I have tried searching online and [clearing the cache](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache), reading [Heroku's Node.js Troubleshooting](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#check-your-buildpack), adding an engines key to my package.json file to specify node/npm versions, but nothing works.

I have ***NOT*** upgraded Node/NPM in my development environment, so those versions are the same.

Comment: `git rm package-lock.json` commit and try again. Problem is probably that someone republished their library under the same version and a new hash was generated. That hash will no longer match.

Comment: @TinNguyen - I read the deleting the package-lock.json is a mere fix, but not a solution as I would need to add it to my project again.

Comment: You can open your package-lock.json and look for the offending sha512 value. But manually editing it is not recommended. Reinstall the offending package again and you should have the correct hash.

Comment: @TinNguyen - I uninstalled and reinstalled the dependency. That did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Per @TinNguyen's comment, I executed the following commands:

`npm uninstall package_name`

and then :

`npm install package_name`

and that seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I simply deleted package-lock.json and npm modules, then run npm install.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it.
Probably you have npm vulnerabilities and if you cant fix them all
try upgrading all you packages in package.json
useful tool is

`npm install -g npm-check-updates`

then

`ncu --upgrade`

then

`npm install`

make sure to delete package-lock.json before npm install

Answer (score 0):

Simply: delete `package-lock.json` and run `npm install`